# Tag [js] should be a synonym of [javascript]

Tags: discussion, tagging

- [js](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js) has 9 questions, no description
- [javascript](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) has 23 questions, and some description: "All questions related to the use of JavaScript within the EOSIO framework"

I propose to make [js](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js) a synonym of [javascript](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done!** Check it out [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript).